# How to equalize height of elements using MooTools?

Tags: height, mootools

I have a div with a variable number of child divs (2-4).

I want to match the height of these divs to the height of the div with the most content (the tallest div).

I have never used MooTools, but in this case I have to.

I know I first have to check how many divs the parent div contains, then get all of their heights, then determine the biggest one, then apply that height to all of the child divs. I have no idea of the syntax though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's not exactly difficult. this is a small func that will look at any elements passed and will pick the greatest height of the lot and then apply it to all elements.

```
var equalElements = function(els){
    // make elements equal height to max height of the set.
    var height = Math.max.apply(Math, els.map(function(el){
        return el.getSize().y;
    }));

    els.setStyle('height', height);
};

// pass on a collection of elements
equalElements(document.getElements('div.equals'));
```

you can also add this to Elements prototype.

```
Elements.implement({
    equalHeight: function(){
        // make elements equal height to max height of the set.
        var height = Math.max.apply(Math, this.map(function(el){
            return el.getSize().y;
        }));

        this.setStyle('height', height);
    }
});

$$('div').equalHeight();
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/h6CAc/

Comment: I'm completely unfamiliar with MooTools syntax so this is a huge help. Thank you.

Comment: I just noticed that the results are't exactly what I need. The getSize() function returns the total size, including marings and padding, not the content size of the element. This in turn makes all elements equal height but it makes them all bigger than they need to be.

Comment: I tried substituting getSize().y with getStyle('height') but this doesn't work. In fact, I am unable to get ''anything'' back using getStyle().